# Reading data from a text file into python

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I'm trying to read a text file containing a sequence and a pattern

agcdttagcdtcc

agc

and count the frequency of agc in the sequence

```
import sys

def pattern_count(text, pattern):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(text)-len(pattern)):
        if text[i:len(pattern)] == pattern:
            count += 1
    return count 

input = sys.stdin.read()
data = input.split()
text = data[0]
pattern = data[1]
print(pattern_count(text, pattern))
```

What is the correct way to read the data and assign them to text and pattern?

Comment: I actually figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

The edits by Primusa are correct, but I would like to add some additional ideas. I believe the syntax you used to get data from the user is incorrect. The edits below work fine.

```
def pattern_count(text, pattern):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(text)-len(pattern)):
        if text[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern:
            count += 1
    return count

print('Enter text:')
txt = input()
print('Enter pattern:')
pat = input()
print(pattern_count(txt, pat))
```

Because `input` is a Python keyword, trying to redefine it may result in errors. This is also why I gave the input variable other names.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out! It needed two corrections:

```
import sys

def pattern_count(text, pattern):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(text)-len(pattern)+1):
        if text[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern:
            count += 1
    return count 

input = sys.stdin.read()
data = input.split()
text = data[0]
pattern = data[1]
print(pattern_count(text, pattern))
```